# Error at pthread_join

Tags: c, multithreading, pthread-join

My program needs to create some threads, but I'm stuck at pthread_join, as it always goes into the error case, because the return ( safe ) is 3, instead of 0, which I assume is the correct number in case everything goes okay.

Edit: To better explain myself, the error is that the code is entering the error handling area, when it is not supposed to, which translates for me getting a "Error waiting: Successful" message.

```
int main() {    

  pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS];
  int a, i, resultado, safe ;
  char *f ;

  f = (char *)malloc(sizeof(SIZEFICHEIRO));
  a = randomnum(4);
  f = pickfile(a, f);

  for ( i=0; i<NUM_THREADS ; i++ )
  {
    safe = pthread_create( &tids[i] , NULL , (void *)verificador , (void *) f) ;
    if ( safe != 0 )
        perror ("Error creating threads");
  }

  for ( i=0; i<NUM_THREADS ; i++ )
  {
    safe = pthread_join( tids[i], (void **)&resultado ) ;
    if ( safe != 0 )     // Error here
        perror ("Error waiting");

    printf("Result(0:Works ; -1:error) =  %d\n", resultado);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is this `error` that you're printing? It doesn't appear anywhere else in your code. What does the code output exactly? Do you see "Error waiting"?

Comment: It says: "Error waiting: Successful", which means it is going into the error handling area, when it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
safe = pthread_join( tids[i], (void **)&resultado ) ;
printf("%d", error );
if ( safe != 0 )     // Error here
    perror ("Error waiting");
```

If `pthread_join` stashed the error in `errno`, as most calls do, the problem would be that your call to `printf` can change the error code stashed by `pthread_join`. If you're going to call `perror` to print the error, you need to call it *immediately* after the function that generated the error returns.

However, `pthread_join` doesn't stash the error in `errno`, it returns the error. So calling `perror` won't work. You could do this:

```
if ( safe != 0 )     // Error here
{
    errno = safe;
    perror ("Error waiting");
}
```

or

```
if ( safe != 0 )
    printf ("Error waiting: %s\n", strerror (safe));
```

Comment: This: 
`if ( safe != 0 )
    {
         errno = safe;
         perror ("Error waiting");
    } `

failed.
This: 
` safe = errno ;
    if ( safe != 0 )
    {
        perror ("Error waiting");
    } `
worked.
But I keep reading that both pthread_create and pthread_join should return an int = 0 if everything worked properly. This means that there is an error still happening.

Comment: @TJacob I never suggested `safe = errno`, which makes no sense. Saying "failed" is 100% useless. How *precisely* did it fail?

Comment: pthread_create is working just fine, with safe returning zero.
In the above case I commented that worked, I don't get an error, so it is for, all that matters, working.
But I'm still reading that pthread_join should return zero as well.

Comment: Right, and I told you how to fix it. You have the same bug in both the `pthread_create` and the `pthread_join` case. Did you try my suggestion? And if so, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Did exactly as in your solution. This is what I got:
" Error waiting: Success
  Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
  Error waiting: Success
  Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
  Error waiting: No such process
  Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
  Error waiting: No such process
  Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
  Error waiting: No such process
  Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
  Error waiting: No such process
  Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0 "

Comment: "No such process" means that either the thread was detached or something else joined it. (Can you paste the code you actually tested? Something seems odd about that output.)

Comment: @TJacob See my comment above. You got them both wrong. In any event, I can tell from the output that the main problem is that either you're detaching the threads or you're joining them elsewhere. Audit all other calls to `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code:

```
int main() 

{   

  pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS];
  int a, i, resultado, safe ;
  char *f ;

  f = (char *)malloc(sizeof(SIZEFICHEIRO));
  a = randomnum(4);
  f = pickfile(a, f);

  for ( i=0; i<NUM_THREADS ; i++ )
  {
    safe = pthread_create( &tids[i] , NULL , (void *)verificador , (void *) f) ;
    if ( safe != 0 )
        perror ("Error creating threads");
  }

  for ( i=0; i<NUM_THREADS ; i++ )
  {
    safe = pthread_join( tids[i], (void **)&resultado ) ;
    if ( error != 0 )
        errno = safe;
        perror ("Error waiting");

    printf("Result(0:Works ; -1:error) =  %d\n", resultado);
  }
}
```

Result was:

```
Error waiting: Success
Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
Error waiting: Success
Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
Error waiting: No such process
Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
Error waiting: No such process
Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
Error waiting: No such process
Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
Error waiting: No such process
Result(0:Works ; -1:error) = 0
```

Comment: You broke both of them! In the first one, you still call `perror`, even though `errno` is not set. In the second one, you left out the braces, so the `perror` line runs no matter what.